# How can I determine the current ephemeral-storage usage of a running Kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, disk-access

How can I tell with `kubectl` how much [ephemeral storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#local-ephemeral-storage) a pod is currently using?

In a Kubernetes pod spec, I can specify resource requests and limits for CPU, memory, and ephemeral storage:

```
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "60Mi"
    cpu: "70m"
    ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
  limits:
    memory: "65Mi"
    cpu: "75m"
    ephemeral-storage: "4Gi"
```

However, to set good requests and limits on ephemeral storage, I need to know what this value actually is for a running pod, which I can't figure out. I can get CPU and memory usage using `kubectl top pod`, but, from what I can tell, [ephemeral storage usage is only actually calculated when making an actual eviction decision](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/30a06af453059ffe636f483b7db914d51757139a/pkg/kubelet/eviction/eviction_manager.go#L503).

Answer (score 20):

You can do this through the raw command.

`kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/(your-node-name)/proxy/stats/summary"`

There is also this

`kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/(your-node-name)/proxy/metrics/cadvisor""`

EDIT:

I've created a Prometheus exporter for this now.

https://github.com/jmcgrath207/k8s-ephemeral-storage-metrics

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's common to disable anonymous authentication to the kubelet API, so using the node proxy is a good way around that.

Note that access to "nodes/proxy" should ONLY be granted to admins since it can be used to escalate privileges.

Comment: To select a single pod by name, you can pipe the output of that command to `jq '.pods[] | select(.podRef.name == "mypodname")'`

Comment: Does not work for k8s v1.26.5 and/or microk8s though...

Comment: i have a related open question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77186330/5889962 , if anyone can answer ??

Answer (score 9):

The pure raw approach for this is to use the [disk usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)) (du) Unix command line.

Shell into your pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -it <pod-id> sh
```

Change dirs to the mount point of your ephemeral-storage (if you are using volume mounts):

```
$ mount # check mount points if you'd like
$ cd /mnt/of/ephemeral
$ du .
```

If you are not using volume mounts:

```
$ du .
```

There are other tools that you can use to get metrics:

- [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) also embedded into the kubelet code, exposed under the `/stats/summary` or `/metrics` endpoint. More info [here](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/metrics). An example output:

  ```
  $ curl -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Redacted>' \
  https://node-hostname:10250/stats/summary

  {
   "node": {
     "nodeName": "node-hostname",
     "systemContainers": [
      {
       "name": "kubelet",
      ...
      "volume": [
       {
        "time": "2018-11-08T23:52:03Z",
        "availableBytes": 1969168384,
        "capacityBytes": 1969180672,
        "usedBytes": 12288,
        "inodesFree": 480748,
        "inodes": 480757,
        "inodesUsed": 9,
        "name": "kube-proxy-token-pprwb"
       }
      ],
      "ephemeral-storage": {
       "time": "2018-11-09T00:05:10Z",
       "availableBytes": 31057477632,
       "capacityBytes": 41567858688,
       "inodesFree": 4873887,
       "inodes": 5120000
      }
  ...
  }
  ```

  Similarly:

  ```
  $ curl -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Redacted>' \
  https://node-hostname:10250/stats/summary

  # HELP apiserver_audit_event_total Counter of audit events generated and sent to the audit backend.
  # TYPE apiserver_audit_event_total counter
  apiserver_audit_event_total 0
  # HELP apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds Distribution of the remaining lifetime on the certificate used to authenticate a request.
  # TYPE apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds histogram
  apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_bucket{le="0"} 0
  apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_bucket{le="21600"} 0
  apiserver_client_certificate_expiration_seconds_bucket{le="43200"} 0
  ...
  ```

  More info on [kubelet authentication/authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/).
- [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/)

More info on K8s metrics [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/#kubelet).

Comment: "Change dirs to the mount point of your ephemeral-storage" – which of them one should look at? `overlay`?

Comment: It depends on the mount point that you define in your pod spec

Comment: But I don't have any mount points. Ephemeral storage includes storage used by all containers logs etc. So the answer is not fully correct in that part with "mount" command.

Comment: ephemeral-storage also includes container logs and container images.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the node name, just run:

```
$ kubectl describe $NODE_NAME
```

And at the very end the output of that command will include section about `Allocated resources`, including for `ephemeral-storage`:

```
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests        Limits
  --------           --------        ------
  cpu                510m (12%)      300m (7%)
  memory             334164096 (2%)  383500800 (2%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)          0 (0%)
```

---

Note: this is collective information for the entire node, not individual pods though.

Note: node name can be obtained by e.g.:

`NODE_NAME=$(kubectl get nodes -o name | head -1)`